# how to get Timestamp of Assignment or completion group in servicenow

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I want to get Timestamp Assignment Group and Timestamp of completion assignment from service now for a RITM and task.

Could you please tell me the table and field name in service now?
Postman queries would be very helpful.

Comment: This is not a free coding service.

Comment: @Anic17 I did not get you,  I have paid instance of servicenow.